# rightsidebar starts from the bottom of the content in the content div

Tags: php, html, css

I am having a problem with handling divs on my website. I have three divs "sidebarleft", "content", and "sidebarright" placed in a "container" div. If there is no content in the 'content' div, the other two divs work fine. But whenever I add any content to the 'container' div, the 'sidebarright' starts from the bottom of the 'content' div. Any suggestions?

Here are my codes:

homepage.php:

```
<div class="container">
    <?php
    include "header1.php"
    ?>
        <div class="sidebarleft"><font class="common">
        <ul>
        <li style="font-weight:bold; font-size:26; align:center;">Categories</li>
        <li style="font-size:26;"><a href="pol_score_reset.php">Politics</a></li>
        <li style="font-size:26;"><a href="ps_score_reset.php">Programming Skills</a></li>
        <li style="font-size:26;"><a href="gk_score_reset.php">general knowledge</a></li>
        </ul></font>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
        <img align="center" src="images/good_luck.gif">
        </div>

        <div class="sidebarright"><font class="common">
        <script type="text/javascript"><!--
        google_ad_client = "ca-pub-4380835311996732";
        /* haryanamcresults_sidebar-right-1_AdSense3_160x600_as */
        google_ad_slot = "1081438655";
        google_ad_width = 160;
        google_ad_height = 600;
        //-->
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
        </script>
        </font>
        </div>  

        <div class="clearfix">
        </div>
</div>
```

stylesheet.php:

```
div.header{
    width:100%;
}
div.container{
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
    background:gray;
    display:block;
}
div.sidebarleft{
    width:20%;
    float:left;
}
div.contentmain{
    width:75%;
    float:left;
}
div.sidebarright{
    width:20%;
    float:right;
}
.clearfix{
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: can u upload it on jsfiddle

Comment: Please don't use `<font>` tags any more. The 90s were a long time ago. Besides, you're using CSS for the rest of the thing anyway. Finally, **indent your code properly**

Comment: Reduce the size of elements `20% + 75% + 20% = 115%` set e.g. `div.contentmain{width:60%;}` and you get `20% + 60% + 20% = 100%` of `.container` div.

Comment: Oh! The contentmain was actually intended to be 55%, but I mis-calculated. Apologies! And thank you @mdesdev

Answer (score 0):

First of all total `width` should be `100%`, not more than that. Then, `float` elements properly. Here is the solution (fiddle) with updated styles  http://jsfiddle.net/ZTe5w/3/

Comment: Nice answer @noob ,but if you didn't notice I write that in comment ;)